# WP-API: get posts in multiple categories

Tags: query-posts, wp-api

Let's say, I have two categories, '`color`' and '`temperature`'. Each one has a number of sub-categories.

Wordpress does great job displaying posts in requested categories when I go to URL like this one:

```
http://www.example.com/category/pink+warm
```

Now I would like to do the same with [json-rest-api](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/) plugin, via REST requests.

Is it possible? How to get posts in multiple categories (not in either, but in all of requested) using REST requests?

I've tried different URIs, but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assusming you are using V1 of the WP-API, did you tried the following endpoint:

```
http://www.example.com/wp-json/posts?filter[category_name]=pink+warm
```

I'm looking at the code in WP_JSON_Posts class and the get_post() should be able to handle that use case.

UPDATE: It seems there is a limitation with the way the query is built.
Here is a potential workaround:

```
add_filter('json_query_var-category_name', function( $var ) {
   return str_replace(' ', '+', $filter[ $var ] );
});
```

Or even better (without new code)! Encode the + in the url with %2B:

```
http://www.example.com/wp-json/posts?filter[category_name]=pink%2Bwarm
```

This seems to work for me!
See here for clarifications: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39078

Note: In V2 this endpoint will not work.

Comment: Yes, I use V1 of the WP-API. I've tried, and I get nothing. Let's say, querying `pink` only gives me 4 posts, querying `warm` gives 2, `pink+warm` gives nothing. However those 2 warm posts are definitely pink, I get them in the 1st query too.

Comment: However comma works as expected: `pink,warm` gives posts either pink or warm.

Comment: WordPress default parse_request method automatically replace space with a + sign which does not happen in the rest plugin. You can either you the filter on my updated comment or encode the + sign in the url yourself.

Comment: YES! --- I've already did the trick with `str_replace` and it works. I've did it in the code, so I am wrong here .) Anyway your answer is much better because you've proposed a plugin AND the trick with `%2B` which is acceptable too. THANKS.